# How to set the same lineheight for input and adjacing inline-block element?

Tags: html, alignment, css

Using CSS

```
input, span {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

with HTML

```
<input value="gfjS">
<span>gfjS</span>
```

results in the input rendering, across brower engines, with slightly larger line-height than the inline-block element despite both being set to the same line-height.

What causes that? How to overcome that behavior without setting the height explicitely?

I added the above in [jsfiddle.net/fiddleasec/df7S6/](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleasec/df7S6/).

Comment: Don't think you can. `height:1em` gets it done.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: inline` for your `span` instead:

```
span {
    display: inline; 
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df7S6/2/)**

Comment: That's the default for SPAN and is not required, neither is `display: inline-block` for INPUT. http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleasec/df7S6/4/

Comment: Can I give half a tick for a half answer? ;) ... am still missing an explanation :/